# Missing touchEnd events on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I was trying to implement palm rejection functionality for a drawing app i developed for iPhone and noticed some weird behavior in touch events. When i place my palm on the screen and continuously lift some region of my hand up and then lower it down again, i get lots of touchBegin events but only a few touchEnd events. Is there something i don't know about the touch handling mechanism of iOS? **Shouldn't be the number of touchEnd and touchBegin events belonging to each UITouch object equal?**

There is only one view on my window and it occupies the entire screen. Both the view and the window have multitouch enabled. I'm counting the events by printing the number of touches using NSLog's at the beginning of touchBegin and touchEnd methods. So i'm taking into account the fact that a single event may contain info about multiple touches.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. I'm confused by your wording of this: `Shouldn't be the number of touchEnd and touchBegin events belonging to each UITouch object equal?`. Do you mind rewording it?

Comment: Let me rephrase that: As far as i know, unless the touch is canceled by some interruption by the OS, after i get a touchBegin event for a touch, then i should get a corresponding touchEnd event for it at some point.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't forget to provide a handler for touchesCancelled events.  You can get a touchesCancelled call after a touchesBegan and without a matching touchesEnded event.

Comment: I'm gonna try this one. I didn't think about that before, because the behavior i mentioned happens regardless of any interruption like phone calls or something like that.

Comment: I tried it and verified that the problem was the touchCanceled events just like you guessed. It seems like when the OS is unable to track a touch accurately, it cancels the touch. Thanks for the reminder.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than looking at the number of `touchesBegan:withEvent:` and `touchesEnded:withEvent:` calls, you should look at the `NSSet` of `UITouch` objects passed to those methods. So, for example, if you placed one finger then a second finger on the screen, you'd get two `touchesBegan:withEvent:` calls. If you lifted both fingers from the screen simultaneously, you'd get a single `touchesEnded:withEvent:` call; the `NSSet` of `UITouch` objects passed in would indicate that two fingers were lifted.

Comment: As i said in the last 2 sentences, i'm aware of that and therefore not counting the events themselves, but the number of touches in the events.

Comment: I misread your question. It's likely the touchesCancelled events then, as described in hotpaw2's answer.